# Avoiding code duplication for data type with lots of similar constructors

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm working on a writing simple parser in Haskell and have this datatype which holds the results of the parse.

```
data AST = Imm Integer
    | ArgName String
    | Arg Integer
    | Add AST AST
    | Sub AST AST
    | Mul AST AST
    | Div AST AST
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

The problem comes when I want to map over the tree to replace variable names with its reference number using a map. I have to write this code

```
refVars :: M.Map String Integer -> AST -> Maybe AST
refVars d (ArgName s) = case d M.!? s of
                            Just n -> Just (Arg n)
                            Nothing -> Nothing
refVars _ (Imm n)     = Just $ Imm n
refVars _ (Arg n)     = Just $ Arg n                       
refVars d (Add a1 a2) = Add <$> refVars d a1 <*> refVars d a2
refVars d (Sub a1 a2) = Sub <$> refVars d a1 <*> refVars d a2
refVars d (Mul a1 a2) = Mul <$> refVars d a1 <*> refVars d a2
refVars d (Div a1 a2) = Div <$> refVars d a1 <*> refVars d a2
```

Which seems incredibly redundant. Ideally I'd want to have one pattern which matches any (op a1 a2) but Haskell won't allow that. Any suggestions?

Comment: Abstract it away in an `data Operator = Add | Sub | Mul | Div`, and write a `data AST = IMM Integer | ArgName String | Arg Integer | Operation Operator AST AST`.

Comment: ...and then define smart constructors mimicking `add x y`. You could even make it pattern synonyms `pattern (:+) :: AST -> AST -> AST; pattern x:+y = Operation Add x y`, though pattern synonyms are a bit of an oddball.

Comment: Do you ever have an expression with both `ArgName` and `Arg` leaves, or do these represent distinct phases of interpretation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As proposed [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640325/avoiding-code-duplication-for-data-type-with-lots-of-similar-constructors/62641576#comment110775061_62640325), the fix for your immediate problem is to move the information about the operator type out of the constructor:

```hs
data Op = Add | Sub | Mul | Div
data AST = Imm Integer
    | ArgName String
    | Arg Integer
    | Op Op AST AST
```

This datatype has one constructor for all of the binary operations, so you only need one line to take it apart:

```hs
refVars :: M.Map String Integer -> AST -> Maybe AST
refVars d (ArgName s)   = Arg <$> d !? s
refVars _ (Imm n)       = Just $ Imm n
refVars _ (Arg n)       = Just $ Arg n                       
refVars d (Op op a1 a2) = Op op <$> refVars d a1 <*> refVars d a2
```

You can handle all different types of binary operators without modifying `refVars`, but if you add different syntactic forms to your AST you'll have to add clauses to `refVars`.

```hs
data AST = -- other constructors as before
    | Ternary AST AST AST
    | List [AST]
    | Call AST [AST]  -- function and args

refVars -- other clauses as before
refVars d (Ternary cond tt ff) = Ternary <$> refVars d cond <*> refVars d tt <*> refVars d ff
refVars d (List l) = List <$> traverse (refVars d) l
refVars d (Call f args) = Call <$> refVars d f <*> traverse (refVars d) args
```

So it's still tedious - all this code does is traverse the tree to the leaves, whereupon `refVars` can scrutinise whether the leaf is an `ArgName` or otherwise. The interesting part of `refVars` is the one `ArgName` line; the remaining six lines of the function are pure boilerplate.

It'd be nice if we could define "traverse the tree" separately from "handle `ArgName`s". This is where *generic programming* comes in. There are lots of generic programming libraries out there, each with its own style and approach, but I'll demonstrate using [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

The [`Control.Lens.Plated`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html) module defines a [`Plated`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#t:Plated) class for types which know how to access their children. The deal is: you show `lens` how to access your children (by passing them to a callback `g`), and `lens` can recursively apply that to access the children's children and so on.

```hs
instance Plated AST where
    plate g (Op op a1 a2) = Op op <$> g a1 <*> g a2
    plate g (Ternary cond tt ff) = Ternary <$> g cond <*> g tt <*> g ff
    plate g (List l) = List <$> traverse g l
    plate g (Call f args) = Call <$> g f <*> traverse g args
    plate _ a = pure a
```

> **Aside**: you might object that even writing `plate` clause-by-clause is rather too much boilerplate. The compiler should be able to locate
> the `AST`'s children for you. `lens` has your back — there's a default
> implementation of `plate` for any type which is an instance of
> [`Data`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html#t:Data),
> so you should be able to slap `deriving Data` onto `AST` and leave the
> `Plated` instance empty.

Now we can implement `refVars` using [`transformM :: (Monad m, Plated a) => (a -> m a) -> a -> m a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.2/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:transformM).

```hs
refVars :: M.Map String Integer -> AST -> Maybe AST
refVars d = transformM $ \case
    ArgName s -> Arg <$> d !? s
    x -> Just x
```

`transformM` takes a (monadic) transformation function and applies that to every descendant of the AST. Our transformation function searches for `ArgName` nodes and replaces them with `Arg` nodes, leaving any non-`ArgName`s unchanged.

For a more detailed explanation, see [this paper](https://ndmitchell.com/downloads/paper-uniform_boilerplate_and_list_processing-30_sep_2007.pdf) (or [the accompanying slides](https://ndmitchell.com/downloads/slides-uniform_boilerplate_and_list_processing-30_sep_2007.pdf), if you prefer) by Neil Mitchell. It's what the `Plated` module is based on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it with Edward Kmett's [`recursion-schemes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.1.3) package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH
import qualified Data.Map as M

data AST = Imm Integer
    | ArgName String
    | Arg Integer
    | Add AST AST
    | Sub AST AST
    | Mul AST AST
    | Div AST AST
    deriving (Show, Eq)

makeBaseFunctor ''AST

refVars :: M.Map String Integer -> AST -> Maybe AST
refVars d (ArgName s) = case d M.!? s of
                            Just n -> Just (Arg n)
                            Nothing -> Nothing
refVars d a = fmap embed . traverse (refVars d) . project $ a
```

This works because your `refVars` function recurses just like a `traverse`. Doing `makeBaseFunctor ''AST` creates an auxiliary type based on your original type that has a `Traversable` instance. We then use `project` to switch to the auxiliary type, `traverse` to do the recursion, and `embed` to switch back to your type.

Side note: you can simplify the `ArgName` case to just `refVars d (ArgName s) = Arg <$> d M.!? s`.

Comment: I think you can use [`transverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.1.3/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:transverse) to do the traversing for you: `refVars d = transverse $ \case { ArgName s -> Arg <$> d !? s; x -> pure x }`